# Does form tag have attribute type?

Tags: html

I'm reading a blog post about advantages of React over vanillaJS ([here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/why-frameworks-matter/)), when I came across `<form type='submit'>`. The full excerpt is

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Search Hacker News with React</h1>
    <form type="submit" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
      <button type="text">Search</button>
    </form>

    {/* show the list of items */}
  </div>
);
}
```

I can't find `type` for `<form>` anywhere or on MDN. I also can't find it in react docs. Is this a typo?

Comment: No form  have no  type attribute

Comment: there is no type attribute to the form in react

Comment: Ok, so it is an author typo.

Comment: There also is no button type `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Its correct code just you have to remove the type

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Search Hacker News with React</h1>
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
      <button type="text">Search</button>
    </form>

    {/* show the list of items */}
  </div>
);
}
```

and code what you `onSubmit` should do, something like following

```
onSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

You're good to go!!